# When I look through the camera a silver wall appears

Tags: modeling, rendering, image

When I try to look at the camera this silver wall appears...someone can help me??[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong here. That "silver wall" is just the properly lit part of the scene that the camera sees. If you go to Camera view, like you have, you get to see more of the scene than is in the camera's field of vision, and thus more than will be rendered, and the area inside the rectangle is what will be rendered from that camera in that position.